# Where can I download 802.11n drivers for RTL8188CE?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

Where can I go and download free software for 802.11n technology for RTL8188CE drive/adapter 802.11 b/g/n?  I need the full power of the n technology since the n technology in the adapter I have was in its preliminary developmental stages. I have a mini pc and operate with Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).  Select 8188CE and then download the Windows driver.